# Not able to push data in vue

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to push an array that looks like this

```
"role 1" => [
    "role" => "role 1",
    "hours" => "4"
];
```

in vue, but I'm getting this error

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')

here is my code

```
<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            roleName: null,
            roleHours: null,
            resources: {},
        }
    },
    methods: {
        newRole(){
            axios.put(`/role/create`, {
                role: this.roleName,
                hours: this.roleHours
            }).then(response => {
                    Object.values(response.data).forEach(data => {
                        this.resources[data.role].push(data);
                    });
                }
            })
        },
    },
    mounted(){

    }
}
</script>
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with my code.

Comment: You can `console.log(data.role, this.resources[data.role]);` for example or use step-by-step debugging in the browser. Time to learn to work with those. You can also install the Vue Dev Tools for Chrome - they help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `this.resources[data.role]` is not defined as array, try to check if it exists then push else assign an empty array then push :

```js
 Object.values(response.data).forEach(data => {
     if(!this.resources[data.role]){
       this.resources[data.role] = [];
     }  
     
    this.resources[data.role].push(data);
});
```